# Is there a way to get Service health and information for Office365 via the Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, azure-ad-graph-api, health-monitoring

Is there a way to get Service health and information for Office365 via the Graph API?

We are trying to make calls from our global monitoring tool to help us monitor O365 alongside other things.

When I went to [office 365 docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/) it told me to use the Graph API, but then I was unable to figure how to get service health information from the graph api, despite looking through the graph api docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get service heath for O365, you should use [Office 365 Service Communications API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference).

Remember to add `ServiceHealth.Read` permission to your application.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, so I misunderstood when it said use the graph api.